# Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons

Tags: windows, networking, remote-access, remote-desktop, rdp

I am able to ping the IP-address of a machine but I am unable to establish a remote desktop connection . When I try to do so it says:

> Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one of these
>   reasons:
>
> ```
> 1) Remote access to the server is not enabled
> 2) The remote computer is turned off
> 3) The remote computer is not available on the network
> ```
>
> Make sure the remote computer is turned on and connected to the network, and that remote access is enabled."

...any help?

Comment: So it will be one of those (3) reasons. What's the question here?

Comment: **What** operating system are the machines? **How** are you attempting to remote to it (what program or command)?

Answer (score 1):

If you can ping it, it means it's turned on. If you can ping it, it means the computer is available on the network... which one of the possibility remains? Only one.

Check your firewall rules. Check that VNC Server (or whatever service are you trying to use is running properly). Without other details, our answer can't be more precise.

However, this question is likely to be migrated to http://serverfault.com.

Comment: @lanz It seems I just finished to say the same. So, only the point `1)` seems to be the problem. Check your firewall rules and ensure that the service is running properly... oh... I already have said it.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you haven't turned off the remote computer, so let's look on the other parts of the error message, i.e. 1) and 3).

As part 1) of the message suggests: Most likely you **haven't enabled remote access** on the remote computer yet.

How you can enable it, is described [here on the SuperUser forum](https://superuser.com/a/1691877/146810).

Regarding the other reason mentioned by the error message (**"2) The remote computer is not available on the network"**):

The link above also describes how you can change the default listening port 3389 for RDP (remote desktop protocol) in case it is blocked by the firewall.

Please check as well, if you need a VPN tunnel to establish a remote connection. This is the case in most corporate networks (especially if you're working from home).

Last, but not least, check that your network is running as it should (VDSL or cable modem/router) - keep in mind your modem/router usually also has a firewall: check it and find out if it is blocking.

Finally, one reason could be that the hostname you entered cannot be resolved by DNS (domain name service). Check if you configured DNS correctly on both PCs - and as workaround you can use the remote PCs IP address to connect.